# not stopping all threads in gdb

Tags: c, gdb, pthreads

GDB normally stops all threads if a breakpoint is reached (or Ctrl+C is pressed in the GDB shell). I'm aware that commands like scheduler-locking and schedule-multiple exists, but I see no possibility to let a defined thread run in the background while another is debugged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `set target-async on` to enable asynchronous mode, if your target supports it. Then, you can specify background execution with commands. For example,

```
continue&
```

can be used to run a single thread, and

```
interrupt [-a]
```

to suspend execution of a single thread, or the whole program.

In conjunction with non-stop mode, you can examine a single thread while others continue to run in the background:

```
 # If using the CLI, pagination breaks non-stop.
 set pagination off

 # Finally, turn it on!
 set non-stop on
 # Before debugging is started!
```

Comment: Perfectly answers the question. Thanks.