# Is there anyway to allow one application thread to continue while at a breakpoint in GDB?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, apache-zookeeper

While debugging an application using the Apache Zookeeper C runtime library, I run into issues when setting breakpoints with the default all-stop mode in GDB. With the Zookeeper thread being unable to run, the server will timeout the session and thus delete any ephemeral znodes you may have created. Using non-stop mode I can prevent this from occurring, but I lose the convenience of being able to examine the state of any non-Zookeeper thread.

Is there a way in GDB to specify that one (or more) threads will continue running in an application when a breakpoint is hit, but the others will stop running? That way I can examine the state of threads I care about and ignore the state of those I want running in the background.

Edit: This is essentially a duplicate of [not stopping all threads in gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666331/not-stopping-all-threads-in-gdb). The solution there to use background commands with non-stop mode essentially solves my problem since I can stop threads and restart them asynchronously whenever I want to, so maybe we should close this one.

Comment: You mean »…, but the others will be stopped«, right?

Comment: Right. Was that not clear from the question? Edit: Fixed typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Zookeeper it turns out there is a hack you can perform in order to allow a session to continue while interrupted in gdb. This hack leverages a few properties of Zookeeper and gdb:

- You can have multiple Zookeeper clients with same session ID
- gdb doesn't stop child processes at parent breakpoints
- You can ignore gdb signals in a child process without affecting the parent

Based on this, the solution becomes spawning a child process which connects to Zookeeper with the same client id as the parent and does nothing else. Zookeeper clients however have the notion of session moving, where every so often the client will switch which server they are connected to. If you have two clients with same session ID, one of them could move leaving the other connected to a server that doesn't hold their session. To prevent this, the child must only connect to the server the parent is currently connected to. The parent and child thus look like the following:

```
Parent(zh):
  host = zookeeper_get_connected_host(zh)
  client_id = zoo_client_id(zh)
  if fork == 0
    exec child host client_id
  end

Child(host, client_id):
  ignore SIGINT
  zh = zookeeper_init(host, client_id)
  while(true)
    sleep
  end
```

I tested this using libzookeeper_mt-0.3.3 and it works as described. Some nastiness starts spewing out of the Zookeeper logs when you do this hack which can be frustrating. If you can't ignore the logs, you can turn them off as follows:

```
zoo_set_debug_level((ZooLogLevel)0);
```

It's an undocumented way in Zookeeper of disabling logging.

Comment: I should point out that this method is not perfect, and has some ugliness it seems to do behind the scenes. Sometimes Zookeeper operations will fail for reasons unknown, which I suspect has something to do with the session holding process stealing the session. Whatever the case the other way you can solve this with large timeouts for your client in development and small timeouts in production.

Answer (score -1):

This helps:

http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_25.html

Looks like you can do something like "thread apply [threadno] break lineno"

Comment: Well, 'thread apply' seems helpful, but the example you give would cause a specific thread to break. I would need something more like 'thread apply [blah] dont_break'.

Answer (score -1):

You can set thread-specific breakpoints:

```
(gdb) help break
Set breakpoint at specified line or function.
break [LOCATION] [thread THREADNUM] [if CONDITION]
LOCATION may be a line number, function name, or "*" and an address.
If a line number is specified, break at start of code for that line.
If a function is specified, break at start of code for that function.
If an address is specified, break at that exact address.
With no LOCATION, uses current execution address of the selected
stack frame.  This is useful for breaking on return to a stack frame.

THREADNUM is the number from "info threads".
CONDITION is a boolean expression.
```

Comment: That just means that the debugger will break only if certain threads hit the breakpoint -- if and when that happens, all threads will be stopped.