# Is it possible to stop a single thread during debug in Linux?

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, parallel-processing

What I'd like to know is if it is possible, inside a debugging session in Linux, (read: gdb :)) to stop the execution of a single thread, leaving the other threads to run.

If someone is curious to know why keep reading:
I wrote a software watchdog C++ class (using Qt). I tested it with a simple multithreaded program, but I'd like to test the code once I integrate it inside the real application as well. If I could stop a thread from the debugger, that will simplify this testing phase. :)

Cheers
Sergio

Comment: **Apologies** a more accurate search on google let me found this link: (http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Non_002dStop-Mode.html#Non_002dStop-Mode) that seems to answer my question. Cheers

Comment: it is ok to post an answer to your question. please do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [not stopping all threads in gdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666331/not-stopping-all-threads-in-gdb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this sequence of commands before you run or attach to your program:

- Enable the async interface:
  set target-async 1
- If using the CLI, pagination breaks non-stop:
  set pagination off
- Turn it on:
  set non-stop on

Use these commands to manipulate the non-stop mode setting:

- Enable selection of non-stop mode:
  set non-stop on
- Disable selection of non-stop mode:
  set non-stop off
- Show the current non-stop enabled setting:
  show non-stop

References:
http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Non_002dStop-Mode.html#Non_002dStop-Mode

Answer (score 0):

You may use totalview debugger to do that

Answer (score 0):

If that little variation is OK, you could send the thread a STOP signal (not as a gdb command the gdb - that the variation) and debug everything else running. Signal CONT lets the thread continue.