# Can gdb pause current thread but let other threads keep running?

Tags: multithreading, gdb

When I attach to a process, or when a breakpoint is hit, all the threads are paused. I can't find out how to pause one thread, and let other threads continue running.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find out how to pause one thread, and let other threads continue running.

Besides the non-stop mode mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9136036/50617), and scheduler locking mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2657192/50617), you could do this:

```
# arrange for GDB to stop in the thread you want to suspend.
(gdb) call sleep(1000)  # current thread will sleep, all others will continue running
```